# Clone database process

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, etl, tableau-api

I need to clone a database automatically, then after its cloned I need to rename some column names.

Salesforce is dumping into Redshift, but the column names aren't matching up for another program.  Redshift is our single point of truth for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view with needed column names, why clone and rename when you can have a view on top?

P.S. a view is a query that is saved in the database so you can run the same query later by using just the name an not repeating the whole query. Let's say you have a table called `my_original_table` with column names that you don't like. Once you run this:

```
create view my_corrected_table as 
select 
bad_col_name_1 as good_col_name_1,
bad_col_name_2 as good_col_name_2
from my_original_table;
```

you will be able to run this:

```
select * from my_corrected_table
```

and it will return `bad_col_name_1` renamed to `good_col_name_1` and so on

Comment: Still learning here, but can you point me to a resource that I can use to set that up?  Thank you for the response and patience.

Comment: this is a basic SQL concept, I've added a short description, hope this makes sense

Comment: Alex,  thank you so much for taking the time to do this. I really appreciate the help.  I will let you know if this is successful.  Hope you have a great weekend.

Comment: Alex, is there a way to create a trigger with that corrected table.  Original Table has a data update and it automatically updates the Corrected table?

Comment: @Albatross you don't have to sync, `my_corrected_table` is just a reference to the query that was used to define it, in fact it will be pulling data from the original data, just with different column names - that's the power of it